# Base Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have an ApplicationController that every controller in my application inherits.

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
public class HomeController : ApplicationController
public class AnnouncementController : ApplicationController
```

My application (an IntraNet) also uses Windows Authentication and extracts the current users domain login name.  When a user's login name dosen't contains site id, I need the controller to show a view preferably a small popup with site list in a dropdown for the user to select.

Question 1: Should this functionality be implemented in the ApplicationController so all derived classes do not need to implement this checking?  If yes, how do I call this method during the derived class instantiations?  Currently the ApplicationController only contains constructors and no other methods.
Question 2: How do I persist this selected site id with session and other types of persistence storage for the duration of the user session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this checking needs to occur with every call, I would create an attribute and decorate the base controller class with it.  Be sure to decorate your new attribute with `AttributeUsage` as well, so it will be called on all inheriting controllers.

```
[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
public CheckStuffAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // This is one method you can override to get access
    // to everything going on before any actions are executed.
    public override void OnActionExecuting (ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do your checks, or whatever you need, here
    }
}

...

[CheckStuff]
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller { ... }
```

As for your second question, you can create properties on the base class that use Session as their backing store.

```
[CheckStuff]
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public string DataToKeepAlive
    {
        get { return (string)Session["MyKey"]; }
        set { Session["MyKey"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Making the properties public will give your custom attributes access to them.

Comment: How do I return a View Result in the ApplicationController using the new attribute?

Comment: You can set the ActionResult in the attribute (such as to redirect to a login or 404 page) or you can use your actions like you normally would.  I would need more context and details to really answer that question, though.

Comment: What I need is when a user's Windows login name does not contain say "XYZ" than show a view page or a JSON that contains all site names for the user to select?  I don't know how to make a action in the ApplicationController class, and how to call it from the derived classes.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can create an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) that inspects every incoming request and redirects accordingly, or you can decorate your base class with a custom attribute (like the one I posted) that overrides `OnActionExecuting`.  With the attribute, you can force a redirect to an action that does what you're talking about based on the user's identity.  If you want more help with the attribute, let me know and I can post some more code.